# Automated way to make PDF table fillable in Adobe Acrobat?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, forms

Need to fill out a table digitally but auto field detection doesn't work properly when I click "Tools" -> "Forms" -> "Create Form"

Running Adobe Acrobat 11 on Mac OSX 10.9.5

Comment: I had no problem using Adobe Acrobat -> Create Form, of course it did a horrible job, have you tried a different PDF editor?  If you will be using the form daily, for weeks upon weeks, I would just add define the fields manually while in editing mode.  Cause I can tell you, Adobe WILL NOT, figure out the fields correctly itself.  The problem is the document not Adobe of course.

Comment: @Ramhound I suspected it may be impossible but it feels like such a basic function that I thought I was missing something. How hard is it to detect a grid? Is there something I could do to the document to make it work? Maybe print and scan? Haven't tried another editor.

Comment: I can just tell you that, Adobe Acrobat version I used, didn't detect the form correctly either.  Which tells me the problem is with the document not Adobe.  It took less then 10 minutes to generate the fields, by hand, for your document though.

Comment: Instead of gurking around with the "automatic field detection", add your fields manually. The "automatic field detection" causes normally more work (fixing and cleaning up the mess it creates) than plan the form and add the fields manually. You will, for example, have control over your field names, which is important in tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't an easy way to do this, do it manually.